# DAML when running da new

Tags: daml

When running `da new` I am getting this error (indented to improve readability):

```
RepoError (
  ErrorDownload (
    ServantErrorWithContext (
      FailureResponse (
        Response {
          responseStatusCode = Status {
            statusCode = 404,
            statusMessage = "Not Found"
          },
          responseHeaders = fromList [
            ("Server","nginx"),
            ("Date","Sun, 21 Apr 2019 14:20:58 GMT"),
            ("Content-Type","text/plain"),
            ("Transfer-Encoding","chunk")
          ]
        }
      )
    )
  )
)
```

What's its meaning?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or other corporate network? Do you have a custom HTTP_PROXY environment variable? Anything else that might inhibit downloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest version of DAML we have introduced a `daml` command. I suggest you try using that.